# Possible to query a child table that holds no reference to parent?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, jpql

Let's say I have 3 tables

```
Child1 Entity
    -> ID
    -> Count etc

Mapping Entity
    ->Child1 ID
    ->Child2 ID

Child2 Entity
  -> ID
  -> Name etc
```

I want to write a query so that it gives me a list of Child 1 where Child 2's name = "ABC"

Is that possible in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Your query would look something like that:

```
select distinct ch1.id , ch1.Count from Child1 as ch1
left join Mapping as m on ch1.id = m.ChildID1
inner join Child2 as ch2 on ch2.id = m.ChildID2
where ch2.`Name` = 'ABC';
```